# What is the track in the Logan (2017) trailer?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, music, marvel, logan

Here's the trailer in question:

What is this compelling song?

Comment: Seriously though, what about Google-fu?

Comment: @Gallifreian, fair enough.   I will admit it didn't even occur to me because sometimes I'm asking questions that I think will interest others on this site.   People who haven't seen the trailer wouldn't know there's anything interesting to look up.    (Sue me.)

Comment: Makes sense. Nice song, but I didn't watch the trailer.

Comment: [It's not even the first trailer to use it!](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pLA0pLzsnkM)

Comment: Honestly though, what a trailer, holy f*ck!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Johnny Cash - Hurt<sup>1</sup>

Released in 2002 for his album *American IV: The Man Comes Around*.

Originally written and performed by Nine Inch Nails.

Director James Mangold did an [interview with *Empire*](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/logan-trailer-breakdown-james-mangold-talks-us-first-teaser/) magazine, where he explained his choice of music as "standing out":

> Obviously I have a connection and a fondness for Johnny Cash, and his tone and his message and his music. But the real driver in all these decisions is trying to separate ourselves, in an accurate way, from the other superhero movies.
>
> We think we’re going to deliver something a little different and we want to make sure we’re selling audiences on the difference. Sometimes even when a movie’s a little different, the studio’s trying to market the movie just like all the others. [Cash’s] music, in a way, separates us from the standard, bombastic, brooding orchestral, swish-bang, doors opening and slamming, explosions kind of methodology of some of these movies.

Same website also provides some parallels between the lyrics and Logan himself.

<sub><sup>1</sup> As reported [here](http://www.looper.com/30249/whats-song-logan-trailer/), [here](https://www.bustle.com/articles/190724-the-song-in-the-logan-trailer-is-an-atmospheric-choice-for-the-third-wolverine-film-video), and [here](https://moviepilot.com/p/johnny-cash-hurt-is-more-than-just-a-song-in-new-logan-trailer/4131059).</sub>

Comment: “But the real driver in all these decisions is trying to separate ourselves, in an accurate way, from the other superhero movies.” Except for *Guardians of the Galaxy*, *Deadpool* and *Suicide Squad*, which all did the same thing and seemed to be successful, which made us want to do it too.

Comment: Yeah, Gallifreian, I think there's other interesting content at your links you might want include.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  -  dunno, watched none of them.

Comment: @ThePopMachine  -  like what?

Comment: Too busy for a detailed read, but I'm sure others can comment.